# C# Extension methods in static contexts and derived types

Tags: c#, methods

An existing type in C# need to be extended with some new methods, so that the following meets:

1. extension methods should resist in another assembly
2. they should appear like **static** methods of the original type
3. they should also be visible to implementors of **derived** classes of the original type

Example, Assembly Orig.dll:

```
public class Orig {
    public static void Method1() { }
}
```

Assembly Extend.dll:

```
// method, which extends Orig in a static context is needed ...  
// ?? 
// public static void Method2() { }
```

Usage Example (ideal):

```
public class Usage : Orig {
   Method1();  // naturally working
   Method2();  // <- this is needed
}
public void SomeFunc() {
   Orig.Method2();  // <- this should ideally work also 
}
```

The first attempt naturally coming in mind is using extension methods of C# 3.0. But unlike what I want, these (I think) only work on **instances** of the type being extended. In the context of a derived class this could be archieved like so:

```
public class Usage : Orig {
   Method1();  // naturally working
   this.Method2();  // working with C# 3.0 extension methods, but clumsy syntax
}
```

The first requirement (static context from outside the assembly) seems not to be fullfillable at all? So is there another potential approach?

@Edit: I may have not described the problem clearly. The needs are commented out in the following snippet (because they do not work with the common C# extension methods). So I try to find another approach, enabling the out-commented syntax:

```
    // having a class 
public class Orig { }

// which is extended with some functions (from another assembly)
public static class ExtOrig {
    public static void ExtMeth (this Orig orig, string bla) {}
}

// derived classes should DIRECTLY!! see the extension
public class Derived : Orig {
    public void MyMethod() {
        // ExtMeth("inside orig"); <- does not work
        this.ExtMeth("this derived");  // <- this keyword needed
    }
    // for static methods even worse: 
    public static void MyMethod2() {
        // ExtMeth("inside orig"); <- does not work
        // this.ExtMeth("this derived");  // <- 'this' not usable here :(
    }
}
// for shorter syntax, static access would be needed 
public class SomeClass {

    private void SomeFunc() {
        // Orig.ExtMeth("static orig"); <- does not work
        new Orig().ExtMeth("outside orig"); // <- instance needed :(

        // Derived.ExtMeth("static derived"); <- does not work
        new Derived().ExtMeth("outside derived"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Extension methods can exist in a seperate assembly from the assembly containing the type you want to extend. The extending assembly simply needs to reference the original assembly. Any clients in other assemblies simply have to reference both the original assembly and the extending assembly.
2. Extension methods cannot appear as static methods on the type being extended. They can only appear as instance methods. There has been some discussion in the community about the need for static extension methods and possible implementations but, as far as I know, MS have not committed to adding this feature to C# as of yet.
3. Extension methods (with appropriate visibility) will be visible to both derived types, and any consumer of those derived types.

Comment: So you are concentrating on the C# 3.0 extension methods. I also think, my needs are not archievable with them and though am searching for an alternative approach. 
I doubt your 3. is true. EM will NOT be visible for methods within derived types. A class instance is always needed. Especially for static methods of derived types, it is therefore IMO not easily possible to access them ('this' keyword would be needed, which is not available in a static method).

Comment: "So you are concentrating on the C# 3.0 extension methods" - what other types of extension methods are there? extension methods were introduced in C# 3.0 and AFAIK they haven't changed in C# 4.0 and I haven't heard of any planned changes to extension methods in C# 5.0

Comment: Point 3 is true since point 2 is true.  Point 3 is stated with the knowledge that extension methods are only visible on instances.

Comment: "An existing type in C# need to be extended with some new methods.."

Comment: I have added another code example in the question. Why your 3 is not true? EM are not visible **to** derived types - they are of course visible **on** or **for** derived types. But from within a method of a derived type, the 'this' keyword (i.e. an explicit instance reference) is always needed. The same is true for the base type. Therefore, for static methods (where no 'this' is available), they are **not** visible at all.

Comment: I think you are slightly misconveiving the idea of extension methods. Your your first 'need' is satisfied by using the `this` keyword, as you have shown. The second is illogical since `MyMethod2` does not have an instance of `Orig` to work with, and the extension method obviously requires one. Similarly, in `SomeClass.SomeFunc()`, you have to create instances. You have to accept that you can only extend existing types with instance extension methods. Static extension methods simply do not exist in C#.

Comment: thanks. that is, because I am searching for an alternative... ?

Comment: have you accepted that 'need' number 2 is not possible without modifying the existing type itself?

Comment: as you were stating in several posts: the common C# extension methods will not bring this functionality. But this is only what was already written in the question! I am here searching for an alternative...

Comment: I'm afraid there is no 'alternative' - you simply cannot add static methods to an existing type without modifying the type itself

Comment: thanks. I'll take your last comment as answer to the question. If it holds true, it will also be the right answer. But lets wait for other answers yet ariving...

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods or partial classes wont help you. Try using the Singleton design pattern as this may give you the behaviour you require using instance rather than static members

Comment: How would singletons help? Also: switching to instance instead of static contexts would lengthen the syntax. SomeFunc() in my first usage example would always require both: a type reference **and** an instance reference before the actual method. I am trying to avoid this.